# What is the ideal way to run selenium tests on server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am using C# with selenium to build a test project and I have several tests ready. We work in agile and everyday I get a new build to test so automating tests was essential as development team wants to make sure core functionality is working fine.

My development want my automation tests to run on a server but they do not want to install VS on it. They want to execute the tests using command line so that they can create a service/scheduler which kicks in automatically and executes the test. Can someone tell me how should I run the tests on that server? Is it possible? Having VS installed on the server would make my life easy?

I have tried following solutions,

1. Use NUnit and use the NUnit's dll to execute the tests using command prompt. 
   (However, I want to use **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting**) I guess using NUnit and removing Visual Studio test tools would be the best way.
2. Install VS 2010 controller on my machine & VS-Agent on the server.  Use this to run the tests ( But this involves installing a software on server)
3. Order the tests in Visual studio, use the generated xml file and run it using the command prompt. (This will again involves installation on server)

I'm confused here and don't know how to proceed or what is the ideal way to proceed. Please answer my query. Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Either way unless the selenium drivers etc reside on the test server these will need to be installed. In the VS solution I would place all the Selenium dll's into say a 'Lib' directory, ensure they are referenced from there and set them to be included in the project build. This will ensure that the required Selenium drivers will be installed along with the project dll under test.

Comment: If I include selenium dll's into 'Lib' directory, don't I have to install Visual Studio on server? Also can you please tell me which is the most ideal way to run the selenium tests?

Comment: No not if  the lib directory is part of the solution you would need to place the compiled dll onto your server and the required dll's in the lib directory would go with it. I couldn't tell you the ideal way to run your tests as it depends on your environment. For me, I run them initially through Visual studio when developing, but when deployed to our test box, as long as the dll's go with the app, then the test's just run.

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy. I understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Use the server in question as a task scheduler to call another machine which acts as a hub to run tests remotely on machines with Visual Studio [already installed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/27/getting-started-with-selenium-testing-in-a-continuous-integration-pipeline-with-visual-studio/), using tools such as [TestEasy](https://github.com/Microsoft/TestEasy):

> http://[YOUR-MACHINE-NAME]:4444/wd/hub - substitute with your Selenium Grid hub machine name (and port if needed). Please see a section about setting up a Selenium grid hub and node machines. This setting is used if you would need to have remote browsers to request your test websites. In basic scenario you would have all browsers to be installed on your test/dev machine locally, however you may choose to run tests on remote browsers to avoid browser windows opening and closing on your dev machine during tests execution.

**References**

- [mcilis/InteractiveWebDriver: Selenium web driver implementation based on json wire protocol](https://github.com/mcilis/InteractiveWebDriver)
- [Cucumber Wire Protocol](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Wire-Protocol)
- [Powershell WebDriver bindings: pswebdriver](https://github.com/qawarrior/pswebdriver)
- [Dev guide - WebDriver - Microsoft Edge Development | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/tools/webdriver)